# how to get all Overlays via KmlLayer class on google-maps-v3 not noly when someone click 

Tags: javascript, google-maps, overlays, georss

i follow  this [article](http://code.google.com/intl/zh-CN/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#KMLLayers) ,and the code is :

```
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.65, -73.95);
var myOptions = {
  zoom: 12,
  center: myLatlng,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

var nyLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://www.searcharoo.net/SearchKml/newyork.kml',
    {suppressInfoWindows: true});
nyLayer.setMap(map);
google.maps.event.addListener(ctaLayer, 'click', function(kmlEvent) {
  var text = kmlEvent.featureData.description;
  showInDiv(text);
});

function showInDiv(text) {
  var sidediv = document.getElementById('contentWindow');
  sidediv.innerHTML = text;
}
```

but i want to get all Overlays  when i load the geo-rss,not only someone click ,

what should i do .

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach an event that fires on load, however in v3, there is no load.  The map is already loaded after you created the map.

I believe just add the overlays at this point.